# Get all "new" documents from library with query

Tags: 2010, document, library, query, viewfields

Is it possible to get all documents that are marked as "new" in sharepoint 2010?
How can this be done? I already have a query where I get all latest documents, but I need to find out what ViewFields I need to add (if this exists of course...) How would you get it else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve [SPWebApplication.DaysToShowNewIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.daystoshownewindicator%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and the build a query to retrieve documents created within that number of days. For more code see [Getting the list of new items from code](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2009/12/05/getting-the-list-of-new-items-from-code/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CAML's `<Today>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460496.aspx) to retrieve documents created within a relative timeframe of today.  You would query the `Modified` field.